# Change the symbology of a set of points in the legend

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

[image]

I use QGIS 3.01.

I have these set of points, where they have the values "yellow, red and green". I was wondering how I can change the symbology in the QGIS layout editor to only show three symbols, with yellow, red and green as label? I am trying to edit the legend, not the actual map items.

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you're trying to limit the types of symbols displayed on the map or in the legend. Please edit your question to make this clear. That way other users with the same issue will be able to find this question and answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. First you should "freeze" legend elements by unckecking "Auto update" option in *"item properties" - "legend items"* for your "*legend*" item.
2. After you can remove all items but 3 and then rename them by double-clicking on each one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a rule-based classification to create just 3 classes.